# Creating a DataFrame return multiple values for argument 'index'

Tags: python, pandas

```
dframe1 = DataFrame[1,np.nan,2,np.nan], 
                   [np.nan,3,np.nan,4], 
                   [5,np.nan,6,np.nan], 
                   columns = ['a','b','c','d'], 
                   index=[1,2,3]).
```

Error:

> **init**() got multiple values for argument 'index' ?

Comment: You have unbalanced brackets. Correct them first.

Comment: Also, declared 3 columns and have 4 names for then. Next time be sure to separate the code blocks by indenting them. It will make your question look nicer which for more complicated questions may help a lot for people to understand where you are struggling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create nested lists by `[]`:

```
dframe1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,2,np.nan], 
                        [np.nan,3,np.nan,4], 
                        [5,np.nan,6,np.nan]], 
                         columns = ['a','b','c','d'], 
                         index = [1,2,3])
print (dframe1)

     a    b    c    d
1  1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  4.0
3  5.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
```